# SPRING: Статус пользователей(online/offlinel)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

я - новичок в спринге, нужны ответы на следующие вопросы:

1. Как проверять онлайн пользователя, т.е когда он авторизован,
   а когда нет?
2. Через какой класс имеется возможность прерывания сессии юзера по
       закрытию/логауту с сайта?

Comment: Spring состоит из модулей, есть модуль srping boot, spring data, spring cloud...

Модуль который разграничивает права на предоставляемые url, и отвечающий за авторизацию - spring security

Вот пример с [logout](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вопрос решил благодаря Алексею с помощью **Authentication**, а во втором использовал слушатель **LogoutHandler**, который позволил описать логику логаута(насколько я понял - действия, исполняющиеся во время процедуры).

---

### Пример из моего случая со статусом

***Контроллер авторизации***

```
@Component
public class AuthProviderImpl implements AuthenticationProvider {

// Связь с БД юзера
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

// Задаем правила авторизации
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
    if(user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь не найден");
    if(!user.getPassword().equals(authentication.getCredentials().toString()))
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Пароли не совпадают");

    user.setActive(true); // Online
    userRepository.save(user); // Update

    // Если ролей не будет - поставьте null
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(Role.values());

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
}

@Override // Вспомогательный метод
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

---

***Контроллер логаута***

```
@Component
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

// Связь с БД юзера
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

// Задаем действия при логауте
@Override
public void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
    user.setActive(false); // Offline
    userRepository.save(user); // Update
}
}
```

---

***SecurityConfig***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthProviderImpl authProvider;
private final CustomLogoutHandler customLogoutHandler;

public SecurityConfig(AuthProviderImpl authProvider, CustomLogoutHandler customLogoutHandler) {
    this.authProvider = authProvider;
    this.customLogoutHandler = customLogoutHandler;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/reg").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(customLogoutHandler) // Здесь наш логаут
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/home");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider); // Здесь наша авторизация
}
}
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, то лучше стрелочку вверх напротив ответа нажать [ссылка на справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). В качестве ответа вы можете его не принимать указав причины в комментариях

Comment: Я бы хотел указать мой ответ как правильный, а вам бессомненно стрелочку вверх. Думаю, так будет лучше видно решение данных вопросов для будущих читателей.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на 1.(Как проверять онлайн пользователя, т.е когда он авторизован, а когда нет?)

Проверять на авторизацию можно следующим образом

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
...
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        }
```

Ответ на 2.(Через какой класс имеется возможность прерывания сессии юзера по закрытию/логауту с сайта?)

Spring security специальным образом конфигурируют, вот пример конфигурации

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
                //.failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
        //.and()
        //.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
        //.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Чтобы пользователь вышел, ему необходимо в данном случае отправить запрос по адресу
`/perform_logout`. Параметры конфигурирования для **.logoutUrl** передаются в класс `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer`

Comment: а в 1 примере - для какого конкретного юзера будет выбираться Authentication ?

Comment: @andrew-bystrov про то как связывается конкретный пользователь с объектом Authentication я вам не отвечу, так как это уже было реализовано до меня, в том проекте где это применялось